# Error compiling 5 MIN QUICKSTART Angular 2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript1.5

On adding the lines -

```
<reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" >
```

app.ts(1,12): error TS1005: '>' expected.

app.ts(1,16): error TS1005: ';' expected.

app.ts(2,1): error TS1109: Expression expected.

Comment: You need to add it as `///<reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />` need those `///`

Comment: solved the problem thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import the type definition in TypeScript, you need triple forward slashes (`///`) at the beginning and enclose the reference tag with a forward slash (`/>`).

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
```

For more examples, take a look at
http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files